# Existe alguna clase análoga a InvokeOperation para Wpf Devexpress?

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, aplicación-escritorio, silverlight

InvokeOperation es un ensamblado de Silverlight, quisiera encontrar alguna clase análoga para la ejecución de métodos asíncronos.

Comment: BeginInvoke??? que es lo que tratas de hacer?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.